# DES Cryptoprocessor ISA design

Tags: design, microprocessor, encryption

In my understanding, to design a microprocessor, we start by implementing its ISA (instruction set architecture) that describes its behaviour, then its microarchitecture, which describes its structure.

I understand how it is done for a general processor like RISC, but I am having a problem with designing a cryptographic processor, as I understand we can use general purpose microprocessors or use a specific crypto processor for a specific cryptographic algorithm.

My question is if I chose to use a general RISC processor, in its instruction set do I need to define all the operations? Even if I don't need them? ( like for example DES (data encryption standard), which doesn't use the substruction nor some of the logical operations) and define (or use if they already exist) cryptographic operations for the substitution and permutations parts? And if I chose to use a crypto processor, does that mean since it is an integrated circuit that the general operations are already defined, and I have to just define the cryptographic operations?

Another question about x_DES which is an implementation of the DES algorithm, to define its ISA, do I use just what's in the Pin description? are they the instruction set? (I am a computer science student and do not have a lot of knowledge about hardware, so forgive my mistakes)

Comment: As a student you should rather ask a tutor or professor instead of posting your homework here.

Comment: @TurboJ It is not a homework, it is a part of a PhD thesis, this is how we do research, I have read a lot of documents, and again I am a computer science student; even my professors most of them have no idea or little about what I need to know, and since this space is for electrical engineering, I guess that I am in the right section. I have asked to know if what I understood is correct or not, and some guidance. I didn't say I need someone to give me the ISA of this processor or something like that. That's what can be considered posting my homework.

Comment: Perhaps you should take some *undergraduate* courses in computer architecture before you try to do your PhD thesis on the subject.   And you might also want to look at the information on *existing* crypto processors, and the *existing research* that you'll end up needing to cite.

Comment: I found a lot of existing crypto processors, and I have taken courses in computer architecture, it is very clear for me how to specify or implement an RISC or CISC processor, and I have chosen the X_des implementation, but it is not clear for me if I should use a general processor, and add the ISE for the cryptographic operations, or it is a completely separate co processor, in which I can even reduce the processor, and implement only the general operations that this specific circuit needs and the cryptographic ones.  @ChrisStratton

Comment: What you are asking is a combination of things you overlooked in the undergraduate classes, with whatever original research you will be working out in consultation with **your thesis advisor**.  You don't have a valid, **singular, specific question** in keeping with the rules of this site, so you need to either edit your question to narrow it to one, or move on to more appropriate resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define the algorithm to be implemented in your crypto-processor. Is the behavior mostly multiplies and adds? With no decisions to be made? If so, use an FPGA. There is no ISA to define.

If you need a mix of behaviors, including keyword editing and SPI packet configuring, then go for a general ISA.

Comment: It is mostly permutations and rotations and substitutions, there are some decisions, encryption or decryption; if it has to do another round or not... somethings like that. Thank you.